# In linux, how to make sure a sequence of code is executed without any interruption

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a routine that toggles the GPIO pin high/low, and have delay between the highs and lows (using `udelay`), and then samples the GPIO state for some period. I need to make sure this part of the code is executed without being pre-empted by the scheduler or by any possible interrupts. I am running the code on a dual core ARM system so it should be SMP. Is `Spin_Lock_IrqSave()` safe enough for such purpose? I got a feeling my code is still somehow being interrupted occasionally but no proof yet.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable preemption, use `preempt_disable()` and `preempt_enable()`.
If you want to disable interrupts, use `local_irq_disable()` and `local_irq_enable()`

`spin_lock_irqsave`  will normally do both of these, though some "real-time" enhancements sometimes allow spinlocks to schedule, so it is always best to say what you mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. I want to disable both interrupt and preemption, and ensure one of my routine can be executed without any interruption. The routine needs to call GPIO driver (gpio_set/reset_value, gpio_direction_input/output) and also udelay functions. In this case, is spin_lock_irqsave safe enough? Thanks again